# Heroku successfully deploying, but receiving application error when loading site

Tags: javascript, python, heroku

The logs don't show any errors, but I'm receiving the following error when loading the website:

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail

You can find the logs below. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Using cached install of python-3.10.9
-----> Installing pip 22.3.1, setuptools 63.4.3 and wheel 0.37.1
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 66.3M
-----> Launching...
       Released v461
       https://deleidel.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

The heroku logs don't show any errors, but I'm receiving the following error when loading the website:

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail

Comment: The Heroku logs probably _do_ show errors, you're just not looking at them. The log you show here is your _deploy_ log. You need to [look at your runtime logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs).